# How do I display ASP.NET ImageButton on a ASP.Image Control

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using ASP.NET 2.0.

I have Image and ImageButton Side by Side by like this.

```
 <div style="width:80px">
    <asp:Image ID="innerImgDesk1" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/images/advlefttop.png"  Width ="60px"/> 
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgDeskIndicator1" runat="server" Width="20px" ImageUrl="~/images/Indicators/blue.png"/>
</div>
```

I want the ASP.NET Imagebutton on top of Image. I should see image button kind of indicator, where Imagebutton color will be changing. But Image color remains same.

Currently using the above code, it displays like below.

[image: CurrentlyDisplaysLikeThis]

I want it to be displayed like below,

[image]

Could anyone tell me What I should do to display ImageButton on Image.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the image as background image of the div tag like the following code:

```
<div style="width:80px; background: url(images/advlefttop.png)">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgDeskIndicator1" runat="server" Width="20px" ImageUrl="~/images/Indicators/blue.png"/>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

- Corix

Answer (score 0):

if you are just worried about displaying button over image-button than you can do this by using div absolute position like

```
<div style="position:relative">
<div style="position:absolute">image button</div>
<div style="position:absolute> button</div>
</div>
```